# how to trigger java script when someone scroll to that section

Tags: javascript

I need help about this JavaScript.
This runs automatically whenever I reload the page but I want to use it at the center of the page so that when someone scroll to that position it should start / trigger the progress bar...

```js
var i = 0;
if (i == 0) {
  i = 1;
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      i = 0;
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + "%";
      elem.innerHTML = width + "%";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">10%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a package already built for this purpose, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/in-viewport  Doing this on your own, reliably on different devices, can be difficult

Comment: What do you mean by center of the page? Do you mean that if page size if 1000PX, you want to place the top part of the bar at 500PX? Also when should it trigger exactly? When bottom of the viewport reaches at 500PX or center or Top or something else?